# NullPointer in CMIS Session getObject - Apache Chemistry

Tags: java, alfresco, cmis, opencmis, apache-chemistry

I am facing a NullPointerException doing a Session getObject in Apache Chemistry OpenCmis 0.10.0.
I am also using Alfresco OpenCmis extension 0.6.

This is the code used:

```
OperationContext context = getSessionManager().getSession().createOperationContext();
context.setCacheEnabled(true);
context.setIncludeRelationships(IncludeRelationships.NONE);
CmisObject object = getSessionManager().getSession().getObject(uuid, context);
```

And this is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.get(LinkedHashMap.java:332)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.cache.impl.AbstractMapCacheLevel.get(AbstractMapCacheLevel.java:40)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.cache.impl.CacheImpl.get(CacheImpl.java:161)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.impl.TypeDefinitionCache.get(TypeDefinitionCache.java:94)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.impl.RepositoryServiceImpl.getTypeDefinition(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.getTypeDefinition(SessionImpl.java:525)
    at org.alfresco.cmis.client.impl.AlfrescoUtils.getAspectTypes(AlfrescoUtils.java:99)
    at org.alfresco.cmis.client.impl.AlfrescoObjectFactoryImpl.convertProperties(AlfrescoObjectFactoryImpl.java:269)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.AbstractCmisObject.initialize(AbstractCmisObject.java:132)
    at org.alfresco.cmis.client.impl.AlfrescoDocumentImpl.initialize(AlfrescoDocumentImpl.java:50)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.DocumentImpl.<init>(DocumentImpl.java:59)
    at org.alfresco.cmis.client.impl.AlfrescoDocumentImpl.<init>(AlfrescoDocumentImpl.java:44)
    at org.alfresco.cmis.client.impl.AlfrescoObjectFactoryImpl.convertObject(AlfrescoObjectFactoryImpl.java:346)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.getObject(SessionImpl.java:414)
```

It seems that the nullpointer is happening in the CMIS cache, have you ever seen this error? I have searched in forums, but I haven't seen this error.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Alfresco are you running? If it is a modern version, you probably don't need the OpenCMIS Extension. Also, what service URL are you using because that also makes a difference.

Comment: Alfresco 4.0.1 Enterprise. I am using /alfresco/cmisatom. I am using this library version because we are stuck in Java 1.5

Comment: That is the correct URL for that (very old) version of Alfresco. What does your uuid look like?

Comment: workspace://SpacesStore/11123e0f-af61-44dd-a767-15b8c720e229

Comment: Hi Jeff, does the uuid give you any clue about the error?

Comment: Well that looks like a node reference, not a CMIS ID, but usually you can use either one. Unfortunately, I don't have a 4.0 install any longer because it is so out-of-date.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: Yes, it works until nobodyknowswhy fails, that's why I opened this question. Sometimes works for days, others only works some hours, if you reset the session then works.

Comment: Could it be that your session is expiring?

Comment: As far as I know, the Apache Chemistry session does not expire. I have not found anything about expiration in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar error while working with logidoc community version. The error occurs due to service url which I get from the logidoc website. If your username and password is ok then the culprit might be the service url.